# Crop Features image on different Resolutions

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I crop Featured Image on different resolution expect medium, large, full, and thumbnail in WordPress. I wanna Look like this type of resolution.
For Example: 200x200, 300x300 and so on..I am trying this code. but it's not work. Please solve this problem.`<?php
 $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, array(200,200), true);?>
<a href="<?php echo $thumb_url[0];?>" download="image-200x200" target="_blank">200x200</a>
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to functions.php to create a custom image size 300x200 with name `my_image_size`.

```
        add_image_size( 'my_image_size', 300, 200, true );
```

Add the following code to the template where you want to display the featured image with created custom image size.

```
    <?php 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
            the_post_thumbnail( 'my_image_size' ); 
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Sorry Mr. Anoop. when I click 200x200 it's display featured image that resolution will be 200x200. Look like this
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, array(200,200), true);?> <a href="<?php echo $thumb_url[0];?>" download="image-200x200" target="_blank">200x200</a> ?>

Comment: I am using this code. but it will generate full size of image. please solve this issue.


<?php
 $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'my_image_size', true);?>
<a href="<?php echo $thumb_url[0];?>" download="image-300x200" target="_blank">300x200</a>
</br>

Comment: Did u add the code add_image_size( 'my_image_size', 300, 200, true ); to functions.php ?

Comment: yes I have insert this code on fucntion.php.

Comment: But It will generate 300x200 but not on click.

Comment: You have to regenerate image size to take the changes to affect. You can use the Regenerate Thumbnail plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this url https://github.com/bfintal/bfi_thumb 

include BFI_Thumb.php file in function.php file.


<?php echo bfi_thumb( "image1.jpg",  array( 'width' => 150, 'height' => 150 )); ?>
<?php echo bfi_thumb( "image1.jpg",  array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 300 )); ?>
<?php echo bfi_thumb( "image1.jpg",  array( 'width' => 500, 'height' => 500 )); ?>
<?php echo bfi_thumb( "image1.jpg",  array( 'width' => 768, 'height' => 768 )); ?>
<?php echo bfi_thumb( "image1.jpg",  array( 'width' => 980, 'height' => 980 )); ?>

You can add any size of image crop and display in website.
```